# Undefined reference to `kill'

Tags: c++, c, embedded, arm, linker-errors

I developed an application for an ARM7 embedded system in C. Now I want to compile and link it with C++ in order to use some C++ features. To do this, I am using `mipsel-elf-g++` instead of `mipsel-elf-gcc`. I can compile my code with `mipsel-elf-g++` successfully, but in linking step I get the errors:

> /opt/mipsel/lib/gcc/mipsel-elf/3.4.6/../../../../mipsel-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function```` ```abort':
>   /cygdrive/d/Files/cross/mips/newlib-1.15.0/newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:63: undefined reference to ````_exit'`
>
> /opt/mipsel/lib/gcc/mipsel-elf/3.4.6/../../../../mipsel-elf/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function```` ```_kill_r':
>   /cygdrive/d/Files/cross/mips/newlib-1.15.0/newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:61: undefined reference to ````kill'`
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I searched about this issue and found that I should implement my own `_exit` and `kill` functions, so I added this codes to my project:

```
void _exit(int code)
{
    while(1);

}

int _DEFUN (kill, (pid, sig), int pid _AND int sig)
{
    if(pid == __MYPID)
        _exit(sig);

    return 0;
}
```

By adding these two functions, the undefined reference to `_exit' error is fixed, but the undefined reference to ``kill' error still exists.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the `kill` function in `extern "C" { … }`. And, for clarity, I suggest not using the `_DEFUN` macro.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use your suggestion and could link my object files. I have a new problem now, when I use `new` operator or `malloc` function, I get `"Segment Fault"` message. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny You may want to ask this as a new question.

Comment: @Mir: Worth asking a new question, but perhaps a bad implementation of `_sbrk`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I ran against the same problem and found a solution. Add these options to your linker:

```
-specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -lnosys
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the first thing, that I see is, that the parameter "kill" has no type...

But the only undefined reference errors I ever got were linking errors... so are there any libraries you forgot to link to?

Comment: `kill` is an argument to the macro `_DEFUN`, presumably it defines a function called `kill` with arguments `int pid` and `int sig`. Why the macro is used, I don't know.

Comment: @Arkku: I think it's not important that I use macro or define function directly, at last this macro convert to this:
int kill(int pid, int sig)

Comment: @userrr3: kill is a function with `int kill(int pid, int sig)` declaration.

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny I don't know anything about macros, but the komma seems to be wrong after kill...