# Segment Fault caused by using new or malloc on embedded device

Tags: c++, c, embedded, arm

I am trying to build my application with `C++` instead of `C` for my `MIPS based embedded device`. First, I had a link problem that you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8952690/1162154). This issue fixed and I could build my application successfully. In my code, I use `malloc` function for memory allocation, but when I call this function, I get `"Segment Fault"` message. I replaced `malloc` with `new` operator, but result was same. For more information, see the bellow code:

```cpp
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
            char* str = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));      //or   char* str = new char[10];
            strcpy(str, "Hello");
            return 0;
    }
```

When line 3 is executed and `malloc` function called, `"Segment Fault"` message appears on the screen. If I use `mipsel-elf-gcc` instead of `mipsel-elf-g++`, I don't have this problem.

What is wrong here?

Comment: (1) Embedded and `malloc` don't mix.  (2) Why are you using `mipsel-elf-g++` to compile code for an ARM7 device?

Comment: 1. What your means about `Embedded and malloc don't mix`?
2. Because manufacturer tool chain use mipsel-elf-gcc, I decided to use mipsel-elf-g++.

Comment: Dynamic allocation in embedded code is a bad idea, you should try using a pooled allocator instead.  And your device is either an ARM7 or a MIPS processor, using `mipsel-elf-g++` for an ARM processor is wrong.

Comment: @Ben:  Using dynamic memory allocation is a resource constrained system *may* be a bad idea, using it in real-time critical code *is* a bad idea.  But to suggest generally that it is a bad idea is somewhat dogmatic.

Comment: The only part of dynamic memory allocation that is target specific and which you need to implement id `_sbrk` or `sbrk_r`.  Is it implemented correctly for your target.  The tool-chain supplier does not know your target, it may not work out of the box.

Comment: The mipsel prefix refers to a MIPS architecture using little-endian byte order.  If it works at all, either you are not using the tool chain you suggest or it is not an ARM7 or the armelf toolchain has been renamed inappropriately.  Attempting to answer this question with such obvious ambiguity is probably pointless.  Fix the inaccuracy first.

Comment: Excuse me, I think my board cpu is ARM7, but I understand it's a MIPS based cpu.

Comment: @Mir: exactly what microcontroller device (or development board) are you using?

Comment: Abandoned and never really had enough details to be answerable in more than a vague sense, voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 1):

You write that your target platform is an ARMv7 processor, but your cross compiler is a mipsel compiler.
You should download a toolchain for ARM. Sourcery Lite toolchains from Mentor Graphics are pretty good.

For instance, you can try to compile your program with [arm-2011.03-41](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2011.03-41-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2).

Answer (score 1):

The library code for malloc() is likley to be mature and correct.  GNU tool-chain libraries require a target specific porting layer to glue the library to your target hardware and/or OS.  In the case of malloc(), and in C++ `new`, and their variants the relevant system code is in `sbrk()` (or `sbrk_r()` for re-entrancy, though that is usually itself a wrapper aropund `sbrk()`).

The tool-chain vendor's implementation of `sbrk()` is likley to be a generic stub and not tailored to your specific target. You will need to have implemented it for your runtime environment.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should implement `malloc` and `new` by own in my project. Is it right?

Comment: @Mir: Then you entirely misunderstand; that is not at all what I suggested.  Correctly implementing malloc and all `new` operator overloads is not a trivial task.  What C library does your tool-chain use? And does it target an OS or a bare-metal target?  I ask these questions but somehow doubt that you know the answer given that you think you are using a MIPS compiler on an ARM7 and have not yet clarified even that confusion! An example `sbrk` implementation for Newlib for example is given [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib)

Comment: @Califford: At the first, excuse me, because of I thinked my board cpu is ARM7, but I understand it's a MIPS based cpu.
I am using Cygwin and I think it use libc. My device have a OS that developed by manufacturer and it's not a standard OS.

Comment: @Mir: Cygwin will be the development environment, not the run-time environment.  Gygwin uses GNU libc, but your run-time environment may not. libc refers only to the name of the standard library file; GCC uses that name regardless of whether it is GNU libc, Newlib libc, or some other library. The OS and manufacturer are important information, so you should name them. If the OS is not POSIX compliant, it is unlikely that you are using GNU libc.

Comment: Look in the standard header files; that will probably provide a clue to the library source. However be aware that the Cygwin headers are not the same as the cross-compiler headers.  Make sure you are looking at the actual header files used by your target build.

Comment: I found the problem, I should initialize heap size at the first of my code.