# Segment Fault caused by using vector

Tags: c++, vector, embedded, mips

I am trying to build my application with C++ instead of C for my MIPS based embedded device. First, I had a link problem that you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8952690/1162154). This issue fixed and I could build my application successfully. Now, I want to use `std::vector` class. My code is:

```cpp
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> v;
    v.push_back('s');

    return 0;
}
```

When the `vector<char> v;` line executed, `Segment Fault` message appears on the screen. For more Test, I did test the `new` operator and it works fine. I am using `mipsel-elf-g++` in order to build my application.

What is wrong?

Comment: From your earlier question, it seems that your C++ compiler is pretty broken. If `malloc` and `new` segfault on first use, there's no reason to think that `std::vector` wouldn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956979/segment-fault-caused-by-using-new-and-malloc

Comment: The code seems fine. If it's segfaults, then as a work around you can allocate some space while declaring `vector`. i.e. `vector<char> v(100);` and give a try.

Comment: @aix: the `malloc` and `new` problem was fixed and I can use both, now. In my question I mention that `I did test the new operator and it works fine` in order to accent that there is any memory allocation problem.

Comment: your code looks fine, so your compiler/library doesn't

Comment: @iammilind: I replaced `vector<char> v;` with `vector<char> v(100);`, but the problem wasn't fixed.

Comment: @yarek: what's your mean? could you please explain more?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Your compiler, library, or OS are broken.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Ok, It think you are right. but what should I do in order to fix this issue? and how I can determine which of the library, compiler or OS are broken?

Comment: std::vector performs dynamic memory allocation internally.  This is likley the same problem you had with malloc() in another question. @aix: His compiler need not be "broken" for malloc and new to fail.  It is the developers responsibility to provide suitable standard library syscalls and linker script for his target in a stand-alone system.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, your compiler and/or its runtime library are broken.  (You can rule out the OS, since the "elf" target implies that you're not running an OS on the target, and if it doesn't exist it can't be broken.)

Rather than trying to debug Cygwin's `mipsel-elf-gcc` package, which is likely to be old and not-well-tested, I'd suggest simply using a different compiler.  In particular, Mentor Graphics "Sourcery CodeBench Lite Edition" build of the GCC compiler and associated C and C++ libraries is available for free download from http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/ -- it should basically just work as a drop-in replacement for the Cygwin compiler that you're using (including working correctly with Cygwin paths even though it's nominally built as a "plain Windows" compiler), with the difference that it's been tested and validated to actually work correctly.

[Disclaimer: I work for Mentor Graphics, so I can't say that I'm unbiased -- but we do put a lot of work into making this compiler work, and MIPS contracts with us to make it available to the world for free, so we have incentive to make sure it works right.  Also, if you're familiar with the CodeSourcery "Sourcery G++" compilers, "Sourcery CodeBench" is the new name for them now that CodeSourcery is part of Mentor Graphics.]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have cross-built the C++ library for mips. Check if the library was properly built and was really configured for your mips. You could also load your executable in gdb and look where exactly the crash happens. I would think it happens somewhere in the libc++.

Comment: I'm a beginner embedded programmer and I don'n know how I can cross-built the C++ library for `MIPS`. I am using `cygwin`. What should I do in order to cross-built C++ library?

Comment: Your MIPS cross compiler suit is available for Cygwin? Make sure that you are really using the right compiler. There are various MIPS derivatives and the compiler suit must fit into _your_ MIPS specifications.

Comment: I am using `mipsel-elf-gcc` and `mipsel-elf-g++` compilers that are exists in `Cygwin`. I don't know are these suitable?